# Android How to create a Glowing Border or Four side shadow Rectangle Shape Background

Tags: android, android-layout, border, glow

I want to fill the background of multiple size (custom width or height) constraint layouts with this design:

[image: desired box shape design]

Noticed that the outline border is glowing with fading gold color.

I have tried with the following:

[image: attempts result]

`Attempt (A) is using of ImageView tag, but not scalable to custom width and height.`

`Attempt (B) is xml created. But the border color is not fading, isn't the desired result.`

`Attempt (C) is using 9 patch file. The border radius and corner radius does not seems correct at all. (Would also like to know reason of this)`

This is my 9patch file:
[image: ninepatch image]

May I know if this is even possible to achieve?

Anyone please help.